# Pourquoi dit-on "beignet aux pommes" au pluriel ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, pluriel, alimentation

On dit:
"beignet au chocolat", "beignet à la banane"

mais pourquoi pour les pommes, on dit:
"beignet aux pommes"?

Comment: Pour moi l'exception c'est "à la banane", parce ce qu'on parle de "pâté aux truffes", de "far aux pruneaux", de "pain aux noix", de "clafoutis aux cerises"... La banane serait un ingrédient non dénombrable, comme le chocolat? Ou bne la recette fait que la banane n'est plus identifable (à part le goût)?

Comment: La banane semble une exception (peut-être pas la seule). "J'ai fait un gâteau à la banane" est plus courant que "j'ai fait un gâteau aux bananes" (bien que ce dernier ne serait pas faux en soi). Oui, c'est bizarre que la banane se comporte comme une sorte d'indénombrables dans ce contexte: ça tient sûrement à une habitude de langage. Peut-être que le goût banane l'emporte.

Comment: @Toto Effectivement, même chose que pour l'autre question, on dira plus facilement "Tarte à la banane" que "aux bananes". Je préfère dire "Tarte aux bananes", même si ça sonne un peu bizarre, parce que c'est beaucoup plus logique finalement, encore plus que pour un beignet, où l'excuse du "goût" du fourrage peut jouer.

Comment: Tarte à l'ananas, beignet à la mangue, gâteau au citron, flan à l'orange...

Comment: Pour bananes, mangues, citrons et oranges, le pluriel donne l'impression de diversité dans les fruits : plusieurs types de bananes, de mangues, ... Ce qui ne semble pas le cas pour les pommes ou les noix, effectivement comme si dans ce contexte **banane**, **mangue** et les autres étaient considérés comme indénombrables cf. @xenoid.

Answer (score 2):

"Beignet à la pomme" n'est pas une erreur, il peut fort bien se dire également, mais on l'entend plus rarement. Il y a une raison à cela:

Quand tu utilises "Beignet à la pomme", tu insistes sur la saveur pomme (= beignet goût pomme), alors que "Beignet aux pommes" dit simplement beignet fait avec des pommes (plusieurs). Comme on dirait: chewing gum à la pomme (goût pomme), et non chewing gum aux pommes, qui n'aurait pas de sens.

Dans "beignet au chocolat", il n'y a pas plusieurs chocolats, c'est une quantité indéterminé de chocolat, c'est pour ça qu'on dit "manger ***du*** chocolat" (on ne parle pas des boîtes de chocolat**s** de Noël, qui sont un autre cas).

"Beignet aux bananes" fait bizarre, alors qu'il devrait se dire. On entend toujours "beignet à la banane", comme si le goût de la banane l'emportait sur le nombre effectif de bananes utilisées dans la recette. C'est sans doute une habitude de langage, je ne vois pas d'autre explication logique.

Comment: Il y a le même contraste pour les tartes : *une tarte aux pommes*, *une tarte à la banane*. Et dans ce cas aussi, il est possible de faire une tarte avec juste une pomme et inversement avec plusieurs bananes...

Comment: À propos des *beignets au chocolat*, il n'y aurait aucun problème à parler de *beignets aux chocolats*, ni de *boîtes de chocolats*, si il s'agit de plusieurs types de chocolats. De nombreux restaurants servent des desserts aux chocolats...

Comment: Non, je ne pense pas que "beignets aux chocolats" soit correct. Chocolat est indénombrable, ce qui est complètement différent de la situation d'une boîte de chocolats, ou les chocolats sont individualisés. "Du chocolat" et "des chocolats" ne sont pas interchangeables, ils ont des sens différents. Les desserts sont toujours au chocolat, mais certains restaurant ont des cartes et des menus où il y a beaucoup de fautes.

Comment: "Une tarte à la pomme" = c'est le goût pomme, pas le fait qu'on utilise une seule pomme, car dans ce dernier cas, je pense qu'on dirait tout de même "aux pommes" comme une quantité globale de pomme.

Comment: Eau est aussi indénombrable, ce qui n'empêche personne d'acheter trois eaux minérales différentes pour accommoder leurs goûts...